# Error encountered after I execute react-native install

Tags: react-native

```
C:\ProjectName> react-native install
Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\ProjectName\node_modules (794ms)

   error: missing required argument `packageName'
```

I ran the command above and recieve the error shortly afterwards. I am not very sure what the problem is I am new to react-native and was just trying to ran an already developed project. I hope someone can help shed some light regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the package manager.

If you are using yarn:

```
yarn add react-native
```

or npm:

```
npm install react-native
```

You can read more here:
https://blog.risingstack.com/yarn-vs-npm-node-js-package-managers/

EDIT: Also, don't forget to install **react-native-cli**

Comment: Do I also need to install it globally like the cli?

Comment: no, you can add only to your project.. if this helped you to solve your issue, remember to mark it as an answer